# Yii2: Eagerly selecting calculated column and loading value into model-property

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I thought I know every aspect of Yii2 in the meantime, but this one gives me headaches.

**Situation**

Two tables: Client and Billings. The Client-Table holds a regular list of clients. The Billing-table has several entries for each client (1:n).

**Problem**

I want to fetch a calculated DB-Field together with the row itself and access it via a virtual property of the model.

Key is that it gets calculated and selected together with the row itself. I know I can achieve something similliar with a regular virtual getter calculating the amount...but this is not at the same time as the select itself.

**My Plan**

In the query-object  of the client-model i tried to add an an additional select (addSelect-Method) and give the field an alias. Then I added the alias of this select with the attributes-method of the model. Somehow this didn't work.

**My Question**

Does someone of you know the right way to achieve this? As this is a very common problem, I can not imagine this beeing too hard. I just somehow can't find the solution.

Sample code: 
`echo $client->sumOfBillings` should output the contents of the corresponding property within the client-model. The contents of this property should be filled when fetching the client-row itself and not at the moment the property gets called.

Comment: Not sure if I could help you. However, I don't understand what you mean. Could you provide some code (of what you expect)?

Comment: @robsch: i wrote additional infos at the end

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I actual found the answer myself. Here is how you do it:

**Query object**

The fetching of all the Yii2-Models is done via their corresponding Query-Object. This object is retrieved via the models `find()`-Method. If you override this method, you can return your own query-object for that class. In the example above my model looks like this:

```php
class Client extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
  //...
  public static function find()
  {
    return new ClientQuery(get_called_class());
  }
  //...
}
```

Now within the Query-Objects `init()`-Method we can add the corresponding additional selects:

```php
public class ClientQuery extends \yii\db\ActiveQuery
{
  public function init()
  {
    parent::init();

    //prepare subquery for calculation
    $sub = (new Query())
      ->select('SUM(billing_amount)')
      ->from('billing')
      ->where('billing.client_id = client.id');

    $this->addSelect(['client.*', 'sumBillings'=>$sub]);
  }
}
```

We are now done with the query-Object. What have we done now? When selecting a client the sum gets calculated and loaded as well. But how do we access it? This was the hard part where I struggeled. The solution lies within the `ActiveRecord`-class.

**Possibilities to populate the model with calculated data**

There are several possibilities to load this data into the model-class. To understand what options we have, we can check out the `populateRecord($record, $row)`-method of the `BaseActiveRecord`-class:

```php
/**
 * Populates an active record object using a row of data from the database/storage.
 *
 * This is an internal method meant to be called to create active record objects after
 * fetching data from the database. It is mainly used by [[ActiveQuery]] to populate
 * the query results into active records.
 *
 * When calling this method manually you should call [[afterFind()]] on the created
 * record to trigger the [[EVENT_AFTER_FIND|afterFind Event]].
 *
 * @param BaseActiveRecord $record the record to be populated. In most cases this will be an instance
 * created by [[instantiate()]] beforehand.
 * @param array $row attribute values (name => value)
*/
public static function populateRecord($record, $row)
{
  $columns = array_flip($record->attributes());
  foreach ($row as $name => $value) {
    if (isset($columns[$name])) {
      $record->_attributes[$name] = $value;
    } elseif ($record->canSetProperty($name)) {
      $record->$name = $value;
    }
  }
  $record->_oldAttributes = $record->_attributes;
}
```

As you can see, the method takes the raw-data (`$row`) and populates the model instance (`$record`). If the model has either a property or a setter-method with the same name as the calculated field, it will be populated with data.

**Final code of Client-Model**

This is my final code of the Client-model:

```php
class Client extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

  private $_sumBillings;

  //...

  public static function find()
  {
    return new ClientQuery(get_called_class());
  }

  public function getSumBillings()
  {
    return $this->_sumBillings;
  }

  protected function setSumBillings($val)
  {
    $this->_sumBillings = $val;
  }

  //...

}
```

The `populateRecord()`-method will find the setter-method (`$record->canSetProperty($name)`) and call it to fill in the calculated value. As it is protected, it is otherwise readonly.

Voilà...not that hard actually and definitely useful!

Comment: I don't see the big advantage. Why does Client->getSumBilligs() does not contain a regular Query? But I'm not an expert! Probably I didn't understand what you have described here. It seems to me that you just have made things more comlex than necessary.

Comment: @robsch: Lets say you fetch 100'000 clients and need their sums. If you perform a query in the getter, the following happens: 1. Fetch 100'000 clients (1 query); 2. iterate over them and perform the sum query on each clients model (another 100'000 queries). With the method above you only have one single query no matter how big the chunk of clients is you're fetching.

Comment: Okay, got it! This is a big advantage obviously.

Comment: It is worth to mention, that an annotation like `@property _sumBillings` will **not** be enough.

Comment: The proper annotation is `@property float $sumBillings` as with every magic getter / setter in Yii. The annotated variable name depends upon the method names (getXXX, setXXX) and not the private variable.